# Time used by Mathematica to calculate tridiagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays, eigenvalues

I have a question.

I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a tridiagonal matrix of size NxN. Can you tell me how much time does Mathematica need to do that in minutes? for

Size N          time for eigenvalues          time for eigenvectors

10,000

100,000

1000,000

I use the absolutingtimes , but I do not how use in this case
Thanks anyway

Comment: All eigenvalues or only few of the smallest ones. That's crucial.

Comment: All it is possible thanks

Comment: Seriously: `100000` eigenvalues? Will take forever. With _any_ computing software. You won't be able to store the eigenvalues in memory. Please, be more specific about what you ask.

Comment: Theoretical computational complexity is $O(n^2)$, where $n$ is the matrix order. Some schemes (not implemented in MA) with $O(n\log n)$ complexity are also known. While you might be able to store $10^6$ eigenvalues, you cannot store or compute that many eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This computes the finite element stiffness `A` and mass matrix `M` of the Laplacian on the unit interval and the 10 smallest eigenvalues and their eigenvectors.

For computing only few eigenpairs, it is usually a good idea to use Arnoldi's method. I compute here the eigenfactions of the Laplacian subject to Neumann conditions. Because the first eigenvalue is `0`, I apply also a `"Shift"`.

If one limits oneself only to a few relevant eigenpairs, this computations can be performed within a few seconds.

```
n = 1000000;
A = SparseArray[{
      {1, 1} -> 1. n,
      {-1, -1} -> 1. n,
      Band[{2, 1}] -> -1. n,
      Band[{1, 1}] -> 2. n,
      Band[{1, 2}] -> -1. n
      },
     {n + 1, n + 1}, 0.
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
M = SparseArray[{
      {1, 1} -> 1./(3 n),
      {-1, -1} -> 1./(3 n),
      Band[{2, 1}] -> 1./(6 n),
      Band[{1, 1}] -> 2./(3 n),
      Band[{1, 2}] -> 1./(6 n)
      },
     {n + 1, n + 1}, 0.
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
{\[Lambda], U} = Eigensystem[{A, M}, -10, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Shift" -> 1.}]; //
   AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 6.88233
>
> 6.82736
>
> 11.3716

It is worth noting that constructing these matrices with `Band` is very convenient but also not very efficient. In principle, the matrices can be assembled by an order of magnitude faster.